# Ocean (blue screen) displayed on map for request for userLocation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Hi all: this remains a mystery to me. My app loads a blue screen (the ocean) after I push my "Find Me" button, which contains the following:

```
-(IBAction)findMe
{
  self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
  [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

My understanding of the remedy of this error is that you may want mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; in the ViewWillAppear section, but I am open to feedback. My question is, how can I stop loading the blue screen of death by clicking my button??? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I steered you wrong (see what I did there? maps? steer? eh???). See the answer to this question: [Centering map against user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107142/centering-map-against-users-location) - the end of the question was also updated to include a link to more useful info for responding to location updates. I think this should "get you there" (he did it again!).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. Typically too I do seek related questions on this site before asking, but interestingly I've looked all over and disn't come across this post before that I know of. Thanks again.

Comment: Google is more useful than SO's internal search. It finds EVERYTHING and it's usually on SO...

Comment: Haha thank you. You know the biggest thing I find in my code is for the most part I can make things work for me, but the trend it seems is that the first time I press a button, there is a fault, but on the second press it works. So, it seems it is not just a issue with my map, but I'm sure I'll figure it out :)

Comment: A lot of your questions imply you're still missing big parts of the big picture with language (Objective-C) and API (Cocoa/Cocoa Touch/iOS). Also, you appear to be making the same assumption that gets a lot of other beginners into trouble: Xcode (the integrated development environment) is not the same as the language or API. This distinction is important to grasp too. It's like calling the blueprints, boards, nails, and shingles "the hammer." :-) Better use of terms yields less confusing questions.

Comment: Not to insult, but there are some VERY, VERY helpful tips here: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html This link is usually used as an insult by insecure people but it's honestly meant to help "learn how to learn".

Comment: It's all good. I'll be the first to admit I'm a newbie but i'm proud of my progress.